# Burn many .avi and .mpg files to a DVD?

Tags: dvd, avi, dvd-burning, mpg

I have a few hundred AVI and MPG files that need to be burned to a DVD. Each of these files is only 5 to 15 seconds or so, and all of them combined will easily fit on a DVD. I haven't managed to find any **free software** that is good for this job, though.

Does anyone know of any that would be suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handbrake might be an option.  You could probably set chapter markers and whatnot with that one.

Answer (score 2):

The best software for this sort of thing is [DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/).

DVD Flick supports many video imports and will help you to make them in to a real DVD that when burnt, will play on any DVD player.

Comment: I've tried DVD Flick before, and I regret to say that it didn't work for me. It failed silently without ever burning anything to the DVD in the drive.

Comment: @TreyK - I personally can't speak for the burning part as I have never tried it, however, I think it is still the best product for mastering and I choose the ISO option, then use Imgburn to actually burn the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you didn't say what OS you're on, I'm suggesting [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html), just in case you're on Linux.

In case you simply want to archive the files, and not make a Video-DVD, use [Brasero](http://projects.gnome.org/brasero/) or [GnomeBaker](http://gnomebaker.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have a linux computer that I have access to, the computer in question is XP. I'll use either, this is a relatively critical DVD that is to be burned. DeVeDe looks great, I'll have to try it out. Thanks!

Comment: devede is nice I think

Answer (score 0):

[Avi2Dvd ( Freeware ) Official Page](http://www.trustfm.net/divx/SoftwareAvi2Dvd.php)